# Как перезаписать массив при помощи innerHTML после добавления в него нового элемента?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Добрый день! У меня есть таблица товаров и соответствующих им цен.

Таблицу эту генерирует функция table_of_goods.

Ниже идет форма, с помощью которой можно добавить новый элемент в массив.

Теперь я хочу перезаписать таблицу так, чтобы в ней отображался этот новый элемент. Но немного не понимаю как это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Буду признателен.

```html
<div id="table"></div>

<form id="rrr" onsubmit="return ball()">
  Введите значение <input id="good" type="text" value="" placeholder="Товар"><input id="price" type="text" value="" placeholder="Цена"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<form id="rrr2" onsubmit="return table_of_goods">
  <input type="submit" value="Обновить таблицу">
</form>

<script>
  var test = [];

  test.push([
    ['Nike V'],
    [199]
  ]);

  function table_of_goods() {

    var elem = document.getElementById('table');

    var table = '<table><tr><th>Товар</th><th>Цена</th><th>Действия</th></tr><tr>';



    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < test.length; i2++) {
      table += '<tr>';
      for (var j2 = 0; j2 < test[i2].length; j2++) {
        table += '<td>' + test[i2][j2] + '</td>';
      }
      table += '<td> Редактировать | Удалить</td></tr>';
    }


    table += '</table>';

    elem.innerHTML = table;

    return false;
  }

  function ball() {
    var good = document.getElementById("good").value;
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    alert(good + ':' + price);
    test.push([
      [good],
      [price]
    ]);
    alert(test);

    return false;
  }

  function show_table() {
    alert(test);

    return false;
  }

  table_of_goods();
</script>
```

Comment: ну так и вызови `table_of_goods` сразу после добавления

Comment: Так пробовал и не получается. Поэтому и задаю вопрос.

Comment: Так и покажи как пробовал. Судя по предоставленному коду, все должно было получиться

Comment: Я перезалил код в вопрос.... при нажатии на Обновить таблицу. Таблица не обновляется.

Comment: почему в одном месте ты пишешь: `onsubmit="return ball()"`, а в другом `onsubmit="return table_of_goods"`?

Comment: в остальном - код отлично работает

Comment: Это разные функции. У меня там одна добавляет. Другая таблицу показывает.

Comment: важно то, что **это функции**, но вызывать ты их пытаешься по разному: найди важное отличие в моем комментарии выше, и все заработает

Comment: Спасибо,  большое!

Comment: все заработало?

Comment: Да. Я внял советы! Спасибо.